# What is a `to_hash` in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

In my rails app, I see a lot of `.to_hash.` What exactly is it?

```
     def to_hash
       serializable_hash
     end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a method has keyword arguments, Ruby offers implicit conversion of a Hash argument into keyword arguments. This conversion is performed by calling `to_hash`on the last argument to that method, before assigning optional arguments. If `to_hash` returns an instance of Hash, the hash is taken as keyword arguments to that method.

Never implement implicit conversion methods unless you sure know what you are doing! It is widely seen, for example, the `#to_hash` method being implemented (maybe because of “prettier name” than `#to_h?`) and causing strangest effects.

```
def method(arg = 'arg', kw_arg: 'kw_arg')
  [arg, kw_arg]
end

# As expected:
method() # => ['arg', 'kw_arg']
method(kw_arg: 'your keyword') # => ['arg', 'your keyword']

# Intended as nicety: implicit hash conversion
method({kw_arg: 'hash kw_arg'}) # => ['arg', 'hash kw_arg']

# But has bad side effects:
o = String.new('example object')
def o.to_hash # Now o responds to #to_hash
  { kw_arg: 'o.to_hash' }
end

method(o)
# => ['arg', 'o.to_hash']
# Ruby thinks that o is a Hash and converts it to keyword arguments -.-

method(o, o)
# => ['example object', 'o.to_hash']
# Same here, but since only the *last* argument is converted,
# the first is properly assigned to the first optional argument
```

Usually,do not define to_hash when you need it for explicit conversion to a Hash. Define to_h instead.

Refer [Here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/36013-heads-up-ruby-implicitly-converts-a-hash-to-keyword-arguments)